# Rails 5 (before/after)_filter deprecation on application_controller.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, deprecation-warning

I'm trying to upgrade my app to Rails 5 and I get deprecation warnings for using (before/after)_filter. However, they point to line 1 of application_controller.rb. Here's the error:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: before_filter is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1. Use before_action instead. 
(called from <top (required)> at /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1)
```

Here is my entire application_controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  include Pundit
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

How can I fix these errors? My application code doesn't use these functions so how can I find which component is causing the errors?

Comment: Try updating your gems. Pundit, in this example.

Comment: Did you try commenting out the 'include Pundit' to check if that's the problem? Did it go away after updating the gem?

Answer (score -1):

Your application may be not using it in your codebase but one or more of your dependencies is probably still using before_filter. You may try to check its codebases on github or simply remove them one by one to find which one.

It probably has already a pull request on that, though.